# Why are numbers sometimes spelled out and then numerals specified as well?

Tags: writing, numbers

I'm referring to the peculiar habit I sometimes see in formal documents, where a number is given numerically after it's spelled out. It seems quite redundant:

> I need five (5) kumquats, stat!

(Though it isn't always in a legal context, might it be related to [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18153/whats-the-difference-between-null-and-void-in-legal-language/18189#18189) on [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18153/whats-the-difference-between-null-and-void-in-legal-language)?)

Comment: I always thought it was so that you couldn't insist you didn't understand when taking someone to court...

Comment: General Reference. Have people already forgotten how to write cheques?

Comment: Will this question be irrelevant if the language were other than English? Voting to close as not a question about EL or U.

Comment: Surprising how the Q. got ten up votes so far, though it has nothing to do with the English language.

Comment: This happens occasionally when football results are printed. If there is an unusually high score, it will read e.g.  Liverpool 7 (seven) - 0 Arsenal

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The redundancy is presumably intended to reduce typos, forgery, and other types of error or manipulation in order to make the intent as clear as possible. It is known professionally as a [CYA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_your_ass).

It's obvious what my intent is when I rather carelessly write an I.O.U. for *sevum kumquats*, but alas, *sevum* is not really a word and opens up our contract to litigation. Adding the  numeral 7 in parenthesis after *sevum* clarifies the intent. Similarly, if I were to write an I.O.U. for *3 kumquats*, one could easily change that *3* to an *8*, but it is far more difficult to make *three* look like *eight*. The practice appears to be a legal tradition rather than a universally honored rule.

If you've ever written a check (known as a *cheque* to the Queen), you've written out a number with words and followed it with a numeral (albeit without parenthesis).

Comment: This can't be the reason, because when the words and the numerals contradict, legal precedent honors the words over the numerals. So the numerals can't be a backup mechanism, if they're ignored the moment they're mismatched

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica It seems like the words being the tiebreaker and the numbers being for clarity for large amounts makes sense

Answer (score 5):

I am given to understand that this convention is not a best practice in legal drafting.  Like many legal drafting convention, it is an arcane practice that persists long after its useful life, because lawyers don't question their style conventions enough.  It came from the days of handwritten contracts, where it would have been easy to fraudulently alter a numeral.  Writing out the words was a failsafe.  This is why the convention is still done on checks -- they are handwritten.  In today's world of document processing, it's no longer necessary, even dangerous, to use this convention in contract drafting.  If there is a discrepancy, the words control, and they are harder to proofread.  An example would be: one million dollars ($100,000).  The eye picks out the number, not the words, but the words control. I learned the above from Bryan Garner (now editor of the Redbook and Black's Law Dictionary) though I cannot find a citation for it.  I also seem to recall there was a famous dispute involving a New York law firm that turned on such an error.  In any case, I don't use the convention in my documents; instead I use AP style.

Answer (score 4):

The above answers in toto seem to comprise a correct response. In literary terms, the practice is the equivalent of the old burlesque show advertisements hawking "Twenty girls - count 'em, 20! - onstage."

Comment: +1 for a burlesque example that also fits perfectly here and makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

This is a guess, but in old hand-written legal documents where paper/velum was a a premium, you couldn't afford to format a document with spaces and paragraphs and such to increase readability. What they did was to write key phrases like TO HAVE AND TO HOLD in all caps and large to stand out. I have heard this was to aid in finding relevant portions for reading.  Perhaps the number in parentheses (or brackets as my people call them) is just a way to draw the eye quickly to the relevant figures when skimming?

Comment: I doubt it's a major contributory factor in the usage, but I think this is a very interesting idea. I've no doubt whatsoever that there's at least a grain of truth in it.

Comment: If that were a factor in this question, wouldn't it act *against* the redundancy?

Comment: @Colin, I meant the drawing the eye, rather than the saving space.

Answer (score 2):

In my job, I've prepared documents this way for several years, and there has never been any explanation other than basically what @Snumpy says: It's to reduce the chance of anyone's being able to claim in court the amounts were unclear.

It may, as @Sam mentions, date back to handwritten legal documents. Maybe people figured handwritten numerals were less likely to be misunderstood than handwritten text. It may also relate to the fact that, in earlier times when fewer people were literate, there were many illiterate people who understood numbers and could perform calculations.

Comment: Ah yes, the numbers were unclear, but the other 300 pages of legalize gibberish were totally understandable! /s

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this myself recently and couldn't find a definitive answer. The best I came up with was that numeric values in a formal document or contract are often crucial to its purpose. Restating a number in parentheses after spelling it out is a way to ensure the reader that the number is correct. It also draws the eye to the numbers, allowing for quick perusal of a document, say a purchase order.

These are practical reasons; whether there is some historic reason for it I do not know.