# Number text followed by numeral in parentheses

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Where I work, we commonly write out the text for numbers (specifically, numbers less than 10) followed by the numeral in parentheses.

For example,

> Quarterly increase of four (4) thousand customers.

Is there a name for this type of syntax? Follow-up question: any input on whether the following is correct?

> This is a nine (9) -week program for interns.

Comment: My name for it is "silly". It looks like an attempt to be lawyerly when it's almost always just redundant. In my gym there's a sign posted that "guests are limited to two (2) towels per visit". Oh, I was going to take three (3) but that clarifies it.

Comment: It's a reformulatory appositive parenthetical. But they're supposed to be used to clarify. I hate to think what Jim Mack will say next.

Comment: @JimMack It's so we can skim a document and easily find the important numerical information for quick reference.

Comment: Tangentially related: *[Why are numbers sometimes spelled out and then numerals specified as well?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20610)*

Comment: Ah, this becomes a highlighting device rather like bold print. It's just _emphasis_ for your usage.

Comment: Your first example should be "4000" or "4 000," since it is a number significantly higher than 10.

Comment: It would be more important as a disambiguation for numbers like [billion (and  jillion, zillion, squillion, gazillion, kazillion, bajillion, and bazillion)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/how-many-is-a-billion).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yeah, I was just being curmudgeonly. Certainly there are valid uses for it. But not usually.

Comment: @Jim Mack I meant when you read the term _reformulatory appositive parenthetical_. If four = 4 is silly, ...

Comment: Why not just use numerals exclusively?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah, bim! I'm so used to seeing obscure / arcane jargon here that I skimmed right over that. Got me.

Comment: It could be to make refactoring easier. Searching for "10" always finds every instance of that number, whether it's "ten (10)" or "10". Such refactoring may be more necessary than you originally think. I recently signed a contract where many numbers are blanks filled out by the office, which suggests that (some) companies like to change specific number details about the contracts their clients are signing.

Comment: This is used correctly when it provides a number coded in different ways for different audiences. A 27/64 drill bit (.4219", 10.37mm, #76), equivalent numbers in different bases, or providing a measure required by a style guide when the conventual measure is different. Heat and radiation values are likely targets - BTU (Wh) , rem (Sv).

Comment: For a specific geometry, the values associated with two points may be stacked this way. If the lamp is ten feet from a wall, I can state the required illuminance on the wall in lux, and the implied luminous intensity of the lamp in candela. But this assumes you understand lux can only apply to the wall and candela can only apply to  the lamp.

Answer (score -1):

There is (OED)

**enumerate**, v.

> **2.** Grammar. **To ‘qualify’ numerically.** rare.
>
> 1876   A. B. Davidson Introd. Hebrew Gram. (ed. 2) §48   The other numerals are nouns and disagree in gender with the words which they enumerate.

and also

**enumerative**, adj.

> Etymology: < enumerate v. + -ive suffix.
>
> **That has the function of enumerating; concerned with enumeration.** Const. of.
>
> 1847   H. Miller First Impressions Eng. vi. 111   *He [Thomson] rather enumerates than describes..Now the prospect from the hill at Hagley furnished me with the true explanation of this enumerative style.*

The adjective could thus be substantivised.

"For clarity or to prevent fraud, an enumerative may follow the written number."

Comment: Using numbers in nominal or perhaps ordinal data (eg Strong's Number 578:  אָנַה 'anah {aw-naw'} A primitive root; to groan [[Hebrew Dictionary ...
Lexiconcordance.com](http://lexiconcordance.com)] is hardly the same as giving a second version of a string.

Comment: Note: **2.** Grammar. **To ‘qualify’ numerically.** rare. I wouldn't get too excited about Strong's. In the OP's example, there is not much doubt that the words for the numbers are enumerated - the verb simply refers to putting a number somewhere.

Comment: So, almost outside the ballpark.

Comment: It is not clear how the quoted definitions from the OED are relevant to the question, as they don't say or imply anything about the specific practice that the OP describes. The quotation at the end of the answer is more relevant, but we are not told where it's from, and it seems to be about the opposite practice of writing the the number in numerals first, and in words after that.

Comment: @jsw29. The question is "Is there a name for this type of syntax?" the answer I gave is that the syntax is enumerative. The source of both quotations is there.  To ‘qualify’ numerically.