# How to add specific information after a word?

Tags: technical, spacing

Sometimes, in software logs, it might be useful to add specifics (like an identifier) to an item, like:

```
object[5] found
```

What is (more) correct?

```
object[5] found
object [5] found
```

=> space or no space?

For your information: it is not possible to replace the rectangular brackets by round ones.

Comment: I don't think there's a rule in English grammar that tells you how to do this, it's going to be a matter of opinion. If it's a footnote/endnote it's usual to have no space but also see [this question on a usage "four (4)" which does have spaces](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234192/number-text-followed-by-numeral-in-parentheses). But sometimes every character counts.

Comment: There is probably a convention here and the question would do better in Computing Science SE: https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question would be better answered in Computing Science SE: cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: The brackets here are not parentheses and don't follow English rules. More like **object-5** than object [oh, yeah, it's the 5th in particular],

Answer (score 1):

I would have a space. As this is software, otherwise it would look like a zero-th indexed member of an array called `object`.

Comment: Although my question is meant for logfiles (not the source code itself), you have a valid argument here: those files might be read by people, having notions of programming, and indeed might be confused the way you describe it.