# Did vs. was in sentence

Tags: questions, past-tense

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do we use 'did' with questions using the simple past tense?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31959/why-do-we-use-did-with-questions-using-the-simple-past-tense)

Do the following sentences have the same meaning?

- Did she say something?
- Was she said something?

What is the difference when you use Did and Was to make questions about past?

Comment: 'She did say ...' and 'She said ...' are similar in meaning, but the interrogative form must be 'Did she say ...?'

Comment: This question isn't an exact duplicate. It is asking something different, using examples which aren't very successful, I have to admit. It could be general reference, but not a duplicate.

Comment: @Irene: obviously that was my way of cutting the OP some slack.

Answer (score 2):

If you use active voice, then the correct question to use is "*Did she say something*?"

You can use the verb **was** to ask a question in the Simple Past only when you use the Passive Voice, i.e. if you want to ask whether anyone told her anything: "*Was she told anything?"*

The use of the verb **said** here isn't correct because you can't put a person as a direct object after **say**, so the passive form isn't possible.

Comment: This is absolutely true.  I think it's worth mentioning the past continuous too.  "Was she saying anything?" - You can use this to ask about an action that occupied a definite quantity of time in the past.

Answer (score 0):

To make a question in English you usually need one of the auxiliary verbs *to do*, *to be*, or *to have*. Each of these auxiliaries requires a different form of the main verb.

- *to do*: infinitive or base form: *Do you **like** me? What did you **say**?*
- *to be*: present participle: *Are you **going** to the party? What were you **thinking**?*
- *to have*: past participle: *Have you **seen** Joe? What have you **done**?*

So on this basis your first sentence is correct, but your second sentence is not. This is because it puts the auxiliary *to be* with the past tense of *say*, which is not possible