# "who my opponent was" or "whom my opponent was"?

Tags: whom

The sentence in question is "I had known (who/whom) my opponent was".  Would you use who or whom in this context, and why?  Thanks.

Comment: If you had learned the actual rule, which is **"Don't use *whom*, ever"**, you would know the answer to this question. Learn it now, go forth in virtue, and trouble not this forum with that question again.

Comment: In Great-Britain, "whom" is very much in use. You should always write , for instance, "To whom it may concern". Only the illiterate people, the same ones who confuse "they" and "them", make such a mistake.

Comment: Geoffrey Pullum discussed this particular question in Lingua Franca last year: http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2012/11/30/one-rule-to-ring-them-all/. His conclusion was that ‘There seems to be no agreed unitary rule governing the inflection of _who_ where it functions as subject of a clause to which it is not adjacent. But John is absolutely right. Use _who) and there is no problem. I disagree with Mark about the use of _whom_ in the UK. It used only in formal contexts, and in the speech of pretentious persons.

Answer (score 1):

Who.

Few people nowadays use "whom" in everyday speech anyway, but traditionally and formally it is used *when it is the object of the verb in the subordinate clause*.

So

> I knew who my opponent was.

but

> I knew whom my opponent had beaten.

*(I changed "had known" to "knew" because out of context the pluperfect reads very oddly)*

Comment: Quick tip: Use who for he/she and whom for him/her. E.g. "To whom does this hat belong?" "To him." // "Who stole my hat?" "He did." This may not always work, but it's useful in most cases.

Comment: @userNaN: that tip works for direct questions, but when people are confused about it it's usually when _who(m)_ is a relative pronoun or (as here) introduces an indirect question. In these cases there are two verbs - the matrix verb and the one in the subordinate clause - and people get confused about which one is relevant to deciding _who_ or _whom_.

Comment: That's why the only useful rule is not to use it if you're in any doubt whatsoever. And if you're not in any doubt whatsoever, you can write down the actual rule, right? The one that covers all situations? No? If not, just don't use _whom_. Ever. Because it's never necessary except in fixed phrases, like _To whom it may concern_ or _For whom the bell tolls_. Anybody who thinks it makes you sound ignorant is giving themself away as clueless about language. So ignore them.

Comment: @John: there's another possible easy rule, which I think a lot of people follow: use *whom* only when it immediately follows a preposition. "Whom did you vote for?" sounds very strange to me, but "For whom did you vote?" sounds fine.

Comment: That rule only applies when the _who_ is moved to the front of a clause by either Wh-question formation or Relative formation (in place of the more common _that_), **and** when it is moved from a position as object of a prepositional phrase, **and** when the preposition that it is the object of is optionally moved along with it by [Pied-Piping](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/74364/15299). In that extremely optional case, requiring several unnecessary prior decisions (to use who instead of that, to prefer to keep preposition with object by moving them as a unit), that's the rule. Useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain sectors of the English speaking realms who believe "whom" is in obsolescence, especially here in the US. I mean this is a country that calls a bathroom a bathroom even when there aren't any showers or bathtubs in that "bathroom". However, since I was not born in this country, I have no qualms using "whom".

Presuming, you too have no qualms using "whom", then you would wish to find out the circumstances where you could happily and appropriately apply this intriguing word. However, if, like certain people, you too wish this word were dead because you could barely handle it, you need not read on.

Think of the accusative pronouns *him* and *her*, vs the indicative pronouns *he* and *she*. OK, let's forget those confusing terms, the meanings which (honestly) I easily confuse. Let's invent the terms *subject* and *target*.

For example

> He kissed her.

*He* being the subject pronoun and *her* being the target pronoun.

*Whom*, *who*, *that* are conjunctive pronouns. They join a subject to its story.

> He *who* has never sinned cast the first stone.

Whenever you have to use the target pronouns *him*, *her* or *them*, is when you could use the conjunctive target pronoun *whom*. That is to say, to test whether you could use the conjunctive target pronoun *whom* or you if should stick to using the conjunctive subject pronoun *who*, simply attempt to substitute them with the target pronouns *him*, *her* or *them*.

We need to  engage in some slight Yoda-speak, in order to test each situation.

> This is the one who/whom they call the messiah.

- Correct: This is the one. The call him the messiah.
- Correct: This is the one, him the call the messiah.
- Wrong: This is the one. They call he the messiah.
- Wrong: This is the one. he they call the messiah.

> This is the lady who/whom they caught shop-lifting.

- Correct: This is the lady. They caught her shop-lifting.
- Correct: This is the lady, her they caught shop-lifting.
- Wrong: This is the lady. They caught she shop-lifting.
- Wrong: This is the lady, she they caught shop-lifting.

> This is the boy who/whom was caught stealing.

- Wrong: This was the boy. Him was caught stealing.
- Correct: This was the boy. He was caught stealing.

Decide if the following is agreeable with the usage of *whom*,

> She was the manager with who/whom I was speaking.

by deciding which of the following is correct or wrong.

- She was the manager. I was speaking with her.
- She was the manager, with her was speaking.
- She was the manager. I was speaking with she.
- She was the manager, with she was speaking.

Q.E.D.

Comment: What on earth has the American meaning of _bathroom_ to do with the rest of your rant? And I am one who can perfectly well handle it, but usually chooses not to because I know (not wish) that it is moribund.

Comment: What has a blank cheque got to do with civil rights, except as MLK's illustration of the bankruptcy of certain segments of society. What have flaring rockets got to do with American independence but in a national anthem?

Comment: Yes, I suspected you meant that all too common, illogical, and utterly unjustified generalisation of some linguistic peeve or other to any other purported failing that the speaker wishes to castigate. At least in this case you are only generalising to irrelevant linguistic habits rather than moral ones.

Comment: By the way, for the few months in Texas, I discovered they actually use the word "toilet" publicly to mean the venue rather than the seat, in contrast to the rest of the country.

Comment: That rule of thumb is confusing in this case because"My opponent was her" is perfectly fine in ordinary speech.

Comment: You voted me down for a grammatical rule not of my doing? Don' kill the messenger.

Comment: Also, a rule is made a rule so that it's scope is as wide as possible. So that due to commutativity principle, the case of the pronoun is not changed  regardless how the phrase is synthesized: "She is my opponent" == "Is she my opponent" == "my opponent she is" == "my opponent is she"..

Comment: Now you have to create a new rule when you say "My opponent was her". So I pray thee, please verbalise that new rule of when to use "her" after the pronoun is commuted to the end of the phrase. And for some reason, you would now violate the general pattern of commutative synthesis found in romance languages?