# Problem in adjective clauses’ grammar

Tags: relative-pronouns, zero-relative-pronoun

I have read some grammar points about adjective clauses, but I still have problems recognizing the right choice in questions requiring them.

For example:

- *All the students ____ do well in writing.*
  Correct answer: *Dr. Freeman teaches*
  Why isn’t *"**that** Dr. Freeman teaches **them**"* correct?

And this one seems similar too:

- *The problem ____ never occurred.*
  Correct answer: *I had expected*
  Why isn’t *"**which** I had expected **it**"* correct?

Can someone please provide information or resources to get better answers?

Comment: In these constructions, *that* or *which* are normally "optional" (it makes no real difference whether they're included or not). The problem with both your alternatives is you've added an unwanted extra pronoun *(them, it)* which is ungrammatical (the "object" they refer to has already been referenced by *that/which*, even if that "relative pronoun" has been "deleted").

Comment: thanks!So is it like having a double subject(or object)?

Comment: @ Hana: I don't know if *double subject (or object)* means something special to you (it doesn't to me), but *probably* it is "like that". Though if you class ***We the people*** in the US Constitution as a double subject then no - it's not like that (because *that* is a perfectly valid "doubling up" where you could remove either ***we*** or ***the people***, both of which represent the same "subject").

Comment: @ FumbleFingers: I mean sth like this: "Judgers are people WHO THEY prefer..."

Comment: oic. Well, in your example, "who" and "they" refer to different entities *(who = people, they = judgers)*, so it's not really the same. But I'm still not clear why it would occur to you to include *them, it* in your alternatives. All I can think is that it would be possible to use *(Dr. Freeman teaches them)* and *(I had expected it)* in the examples (as parenthetical statements in brackets). Is that the way you're seeing things?

Comment: Yes! Actually I know the first answers are right but I wanted to know is there any grammatical problem with alternatives or it's just about Summarizing.Thanks

Comment: Those involve relative clauses. In relative clauses, you **cannot** fill in the relativized gap--for if you did, then it ain't a relative clause no more. That is why you can't have "them" or "it" in your two examples, for they would then fill in the gap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## *Doing Away with One’s Relatives*

It appears <sub>(that)</sub> your test-giver expects you to produce [***reduced relative clauses***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause) here.  This is common, but by no means strictly necessary.

The first sentence supports these possible correct solutions:

1. All the students Dr. Freeman teaches do well in writing.
2. All the students **that** Dr. Freeman teaches do well in writing.
3. All the students **whom** Dr. Freeman teaches do well in writing.

The first solution above is the most common. the third the least.  It is not that your proposed solution two is wrong, only that is less common than solution one is.

The second sentence supports these possible correct solutions, again ranked from most common to least:

1. The problem I had expected never occurred.
2. The problem **that** I had expected never occurred.
3. The problem **which** I had expected never occurred.

Your own proposed solution appears to have a spurious *it* at the end, which makes no sense here.  It is otherwise fine, however.

---

## Relative-pronoun Deletion

What is going on in all these situations is that the relative pronoun  <sub>(that is)</sub> connecting the relative clause to the noun phrase  <sub>(that)</sub> it applies to is usually omissible in English.  Another way of saying this is that the [***zero relative pronoun***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses#Zero_relative_pronoun) is often allowed here.

This is perfectly natural and completely common, but it is never obligatory — despite possible protestations to the contrary from your instructor.  I’m sure your instructor knows this, so I am guessing  <sub>(that)</sub>  this was a test to see whether you knew how to delete relatives if you cared to.

Relative pronouns are *who, whom, whose, that,* and *which*.  Since we are talking about clauses here, there must be both a subject and verb. The relative pronoun connects its relative clause to the noun phrase  <sub>(which)</sub> the clause modifies.

### Object relatives

When the relative pronoun is serving as the **object of its clause**, as it is here, it can often be safely deleted — and usually is.

- The bird **that** I saw in my courtyard interested me.
- The bird **which** I saw in my courtyard interested me.
- The bird I saw in my courtyard interested me.

Or with a phrase verb:

- The bird **that** I was looking for appeared in my courtyard.
- The bird **which** I was looking for appeared in my courtyard.
- The bird I was looking for appeared in my courtyard.

Note that phrasal verbs can lead to unnatural [***pied piping***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74357/why-does-legal-english-sometimes-repeat-the-antecedent-noun-after-which/74364#74364), as it does here:

- The bird **for which** I was looking appeared in my courtyard.

Or using a human/animate subject:

- The man **that** I saw in my courtyard interested me.
- The man **which** I saw in my courtyard interested me.
- The man **whom** I saw in my courtyard interested me.  (*formally correct, but hard to get right*)
- The man **who** I saw in my courtyard interested me.  (*much more common*)
- The man I saw in my courtyard interested me.

Those are all perfectly fine, and all are encountered often enough in the wild, so to speak.

### Subject relatives

When the relative pronoun is serving as the **subject of its clause**, it is not **in general** omissible, as this leads to ungrammatical forms unproduced by native speakers:

- The bird **that** came to my courtyard interested me.
- The bird **which** came to my courtyard interested me.
- The bird *came to courtyard interested me. (***NOT GRAMMATICAL!***)

However, there is one special case that allows for the deletion of the relative pronoun serving as subject: if the verb it governs is a finite inflection of *be*.  In that instance, the relative pronoun and the following *be* verb are both deleted.  This is what linguists refer to as [***whiz-deletion***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971) — which has nothing to do with Gandalf falling into shadow in Moria, even if folks with the [***whine–wine merger***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_wh#Wine.E2.80.93whine_merger) might be momentarily misled. :-)

First, with a prepositional phrase:

- The bird **that was** in my courtyard interested me.
- The bird **which was** in my courtyard interested me.
- The bird in my courtyard interested me.

Or with a human/animate agent:

- The man **that was** in my courtyard interested me.
- The man **who was** in my courtyard interested me.
- The man in my courtyard interested me.

Second, with a past participle:

- The bird **that was** perched in my courtyard interested me.
- The bird **which was** perched in my courtyard interested me.
- The bird perched in my courtyard interested me.

Or with a human/animate agent:

- The man **that was** seated in my courtyard interested me.
- The man **who was** seated in my courtyard interested me.
- The man seated in my courtyard interested me.

Third, with a present participle:

- The bird **that was** perching in my courtyard interested me.
- The bird **which was** perching in my courtyard interested me.
- The bird perching in my courtyard interested me.

Or with a human agent:

- The man **that was** waiting in my courtyard interested me.
- The man **who was** waiting in my courtyard interested me.
- The man waiting in my courtyard interested me.

### *Whizzers Beware!*

Note that whiz deletion can become awkward or even misleading when the relative clause is descriptive instead of restrictive:

- My kitten Fluffy, **who is** always by my pillow when I wake up in the morning, was not there this morning.
- My kitten Fluffy, always by my pillow when I wake up in the morning, was not there this morning.

Be careful with whiz deletion in those situations; it may or may not improve the reading.

Another source of trouble from overzealous whiz deletion derives from the participle–gerund duality in English. When there is a present participle involved, whiz deletion can sometimes lead to a misreading.  Sometimes this is only on first read, but at other times it is always ambiguous.

This occurs because an *-ing* verb in English can serve equally well as a participle/adjective as it can a gerund/noun — and if it is a noun, then it can be the head of its own phrase.

It is easy enough to construct a [***garden path sentence***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence) that is misreadable, at least initially:

- The genetic risk **that is** taking its toll here will not be seen for generations.
- The genetic risk taking its toll here will not be seen for generations.

In the second version, the reader first construes the subject of the sentence to be *risk taking*, not *risk* by itself.

The careful writer avoids whiz deletions that imperil clarity, although the mischievous writer may have other goals.

### Possessive relatives

No, these are not greedy family members. :)  They are relative pronouns that connect their clauses back to the noun phrase in neither a subject nor an object way, but in a possessive way.

These possessive relatives are usually just *whose*, but may at times be *of which* instead.  There is no difference between those two, though,  because *whose* is not restricted to animate agents  <sub>(in)</sub> the way  <sub>(that)</sub> *who* and *whom* are.

One cannot delete possessive relatives at all, because the sentence becomes ungrammatical if one tries.

Compare valid sentences:

- The man **whose** bird had escaped chased it into my courtyard.
- A bird **whose** likes I had never seen appeared in my courtyard.
- A bird the likes **of which** I had never seen appeared in my courtyard.

With ones rendered invalid once their relatives have been done away with:

- *The man  bird had escaped chased it into my courtyard.
- *A bird likes I had never seen appeared in my courtyard.
- *A bird the likes  I had never seen appeared in my courtyard.

Comment: Nice post! but a) ***The man which I saw in the courtyard***... seems very wrong indeed to me. I'm sure it's wrong in modern British English. Googling "the man which" I was only able to find things like "the man. Which" or  archaic biblical quotes. I don't believe ***which*** can be used for people; b) your example of *whizzer* deletion gives you a sentential adjunct clause  v. different from a R. Clause. For example it can be fronted: ***Always by my pillow when I wake up in the morning, my kitten Fluffy***... compare with ***Who is by my pillow in the morning, my kitten Fluffy...*** *

Comment: @Araucaria Agreed: most of the [historical “manwiches”](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20man%20which%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) seem to be KJVish.

Answer (score 1):

1. All the students(i) *[ (null/that/<del>which</del>/who/whom) Dr. Freeman teaches __(i) ]* do well in writing.
2. The problem(i) *[ (null/that/which) I had expected __(i) ]* never occurred.

The stuff within the brackets is a relative clause. Notice that your relatives have a relativized gap ("__") in them. Those gaps cannot be filled--else their clauses would then no longer be relative clauses.

Your gaps have an antecedent, which in your case are the subjects of the main clause.

Note that "null" means that the relative word could be nothing at all.

And so, for your alternatives, yes, you can insert "that" or "which"; but you cannot insert "them" or "it" because that would fill in the relativized gap.

Comment: Isn't the antecedent for the gap in those relative clauses with a relative pronoun (let's say, ***who, which, where***), the relative pronoun itself?? [I humbly ask..]

Comment: @Araucaria Yup. :) . . . They can also be thought of as being intermediary stepping stones between the gap and the ultimate antecedent. Usually, I had been putting those intermediate steps in there. But I was too lazy here. Also, I didn't want to add those indexes to "who" and "whom" and "which" but not for "that" or "null". Yanno, I actually had recently re-read my post (hours earlier) with your question in mind--and decided I could defend my post in the condition it is currently in if someone came by and asked. And then you come along and ask that exact question . . . :)

Answer (score 1):

In his discussion of relative clauses Swan (*Practical English Usage*, p 478) states:

> As subjects or objects, *who(m)*, *which* and *that* replace words like *she*,
> *him* or *it*: one subject or object in a relative clause is enough:
>
> I've found the car keys. You were looking for *them*.
>
> I've found the car keys *that* you were looking for. (NOT ... *that* you were looking for
> *them*.)

And Yule in *Explaining English Grammar* (p241) comments:

> In a number of other languages, there would typically be a pronoun
> after the verb in these relative clauses. Using such a construction in
> English results in an ungrammatical sentence:
>
> *Did you enjoy the film which you saw *it*?
>
> The extra pronoun is called a RESUMPTIVE PRONOUN and may be used by
> some language learners in the early stages of learning English.

Languages that have resumptive pronouns include Greek and Persian.

Comment: I suppose some native speakers won't like it much, but [*This is the **girl** that whenever it rains **she** cries*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resumptive_pronoun) just about passes *my* "inner grammarian" (well, it's not *ridiculously* wrong, at least). I'd rather have seen this question on ELL in the first place, and to my mind you calling attention to the fact that "resumptive pronouns" occur more naturally in other languages simply reinforces that idea.

Comment: Odlin in _Language Transfer: Cross-linguistic influence on language learning_ (p102) notes: _Resumptive pronuons do occur in relative clauses in some nonstandard varieties of English._ My inner grammarian does not reject your example either, although omitting the resumptive pronoun results in a sentence that I find oddly appealing: _This is the girl that whenever it rains cries_.

Comment: Yeah, I think I see what you mean. Perhaps it's because we recognise *whenever it rains* as an "adverbial-cum-adjectival"  element that would sit more comfortably at the *end* of the utterance. But we know that we could substitute syntactically similar alternatives such as *seldom, often, loudly*, many of which are equally at home before or after the "primary" verb. And there's something kinda satisfying about being able to introduce a "secondary" verb where you might think the two different "subjects" could be confusing, but in fact they're not.

Comment: @Shoe: Thanks for this sentence "Languages that have resumptive pronouns include Greek and Persian." I think that's the reason I have this problem:)