# 1607 writ by Edward Coke - Relative pronouns?

Tags: legalese, early-modern-english, relative-pronouns

> (Sir Edward) Coke further noted that
>   legal disputes about such matters as inheritance of goods:
>
> > are not to be decided by natural reason but by the artificial reason and judgment
> >     of law, **which** law is an art which requires long study and experience, before **that**
> >     a man can attain to the cognisance of it: that the law was the golden metwand
> >     and measure to try the causes of the subjects; and which protected his majesty in
> >     safety and peace. . . .

I know that this was written in 1607, but:

1. How would you determine the purpose of **which**? It doesn't sound like the modern relative pronoun; "which is an art which" sounds curious. This refers to [Why does legal English sometimes repeat the antecedent noun after "which"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74357/why-does-legal-english-sometimes-repeat-the-antecedent-noun-after-which).
2. I think **that** is optional, but is it truly? Why or why not?

This doesn't duplicate; the linked question doesn't answer question 2.

Source: P13, How the Law Works, Gary Slapper

Comment: *Which law* is to be taken as a unit (akin to *at which time/point*).  *Before that* is a compound conjunction and is identical in meaning to *before*.

Comment: In 1607 it was OK to use _which law_ as a relative pronoun phrase; nowadays a non-restrictive relative clause would drop the noun and simply use _which_. Language changes.

Comment: One might also rephrase it as _said law being an art..._

Comment: Would this please be reopened? It's not a duplicate; the other question doesn't answer my question 2.

Comment: As we have told you on multiple occasions the statement "It's not a duplicate" is not sufficient for a question to not be a duplicate. If the other question does not answer your question, you **must** edit this one to explain *exactly why* the duplicate doesn't answer your question. "I still don't get it" **is not** sufficient explanation.