# position of antecedent in case of 'of which'

Tags: possessive-of-which

She had built a funeral temple **on the walls of which** she left behind a record of her reign.

Can this sentence be changed as below?

1. She had built a funeral temple **of which** she left behind a record of her reign **on the wall**.
2. She had built a funeral temple **of which on the wall** she left behind a record of her reign.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: ............No.

Comment: No, that's not the way to do it. You have to put each successive fronting **in front of** the one before. So, _a temple which she wrote something on the wall of; a temple of which she wrote something on the wall; a temple the wall of which she wrote something on; a temple on the wall of which she wrote something._ All are correct. [***Pied-Piping***](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/74364/15299), once it's decided on, can reach for a number of stacked phrases and move them all or one-by-one.

Answer (score 1):

No. The relative clause in the original sentence represents this:

> She left a record of her reign on the walls of the temple. ... *The 'record' is a record of her reign*.

The relative clauses in both of your rewrites represent something quite different—this:

> She left a record of the temple on the wall. ... *The 'record' is a record of the temple (or possibly of the building of the temple).*

Answer (score 0):

The possessive version of *which* is simply *whose*. So you want:

> She had built a funeral temple **on whose walls** she left behind a record of her reign.

Much easier that way.