# Grammarly website: "You can upload a document which size is under 4 MB." Is this grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

On the [Grammarly website](https://support.grammarly.com/hc/en-us/articles/206115137-What-are-the-limitations-when-using-Grammarly-), they have the following sentence:

> You can upload a document **which size** is under 4 MB

As a fan of irony and grammar, I'm curious as to whether the bolded portion is grammatically correct. It sounds really awkward, and I've honestly never seen anyone use that phrasing. I would've opted for one of the following:

> You can upload a document whose size is under 4 MB
>
> You can upload a document which has a size of less than 4 MB
>
> You can upload a document with a size under 4 MB
>
> You can upload a document smaller than 4 MB

Is their version acceptable?

Comment: Your instinct is correct. Their version is not.

Comment: Just wondering - what do you get when you feed the paragraph back to grammarly's grammar checker?

Comment: I agree that this form is odd, but some even highly educated native speakers seem to use it. Here is one such example form David Foster Wallace: "This reviewer's family is roughly 70 percent SNOOT, which term itself derives from an acronym, with the big historical family joke being that whether S.N.O.O.T. stood for "Sprachgefühl Necessitates Our Ongoing Tendance" or "Syntax Nudniks of Our Time" depended on whether or not you were one" (Footnote 3 at http://harpers.org/wp-content/uploads/HarpersMagazine-2001-04-0070913.pdf). Seems odd for a SNOOT like DFW. Or was he being ironic?

Comment: @Lawrence Lol, I've got to try that now. Update: didn't flag it

Comment: *which has a size* would be better with *that* instead of *which*.

Comment: I think it is Grammarly trying to be clever for its own good. See earlier *[Why does legal English sometimes repeat the antecedent noun after “which”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74357)* as well as *[“He wore a wig: which wig was made of hair](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/107066/)* at ELL.

Comment: _You can upload a document smaller than 4 MB_ is the best of your choices. Better: You can upload a document up to 4 MB. We understand that 4MB is the size limitation of the document.

Comment: Recommendations against Grammarly: https://twitter.com/StanCarey/status/710474622031032320 http://www.economist.com/blogs/johnson/2012/08/grammar-software

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Janus Bahs Jacquet observes in a comment beneath the poster's question,

> Your instinct is correct. Their version is not.

Tacitly (and belatedly), Grammarly seems to have recognized the ungrammarliness of its originally posted wording. The wording that now appears on the [cited support page](https://support.grammarly.com/hc/en-us/articles/206115137-What-are-the-limitations-when-using-Grammarly-) is

> You can upload a document of 4 MB or less.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that they changed it, lol.

Answer (score -2):

You are correct. Even though "you" is the subject of the sentence, and "can upload" is the predicate, which size indicates a question, and since there is none, rather, there is a statement, the sentence is grammaticaly incorrect. However, the english reader should be able to figure out what they mean, so it gets the point across and works, but is technically incorrect and should be avoided.

Comment: *which* doesn't indicate a question, it's a relative pronoun. It's just the case that it's the wrong pronoun for this use.