# Ms. or Mrs. if you don't know the marriage status

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it appropriate to use the title “Miss” as opposed to “Ms.”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2743/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-title-miss-as-opposed-to-ms)

To my understanding:

```
Ms. => Not married.
Mrs. => Married.
```

However, if one doesn't know the marriage status of the other party, what is the correct term to use?

Ms/Mrs may be a possibility, but I am wondering if there is a one word version such as "Mr" regardless of their marriage status.

Answer (score 10):

Miss is generally used if the woman is not married.
Ms. can be used with any woman.

Comment: Properly Ms since it's not a contraction of anything, but mostly dead on.

Comment: Uh… where did you get the idea that Ms is not a contraction of anything, please?

Miss is a contraction of Mistress…

Mrs is a contraction of Mistress…

Ms is a contraction of Mistress…

Do you have any doubts about any of that, please?