# Do we need hyphen in this: graded-reading books?

Tags: adjectives, hyphenation

Is it necessary to have a hyphen in the following phrase?

**graded-reading books**

Please my friends you are only hope for me at a last chance salon because my teacher he is not knowing answer.

Comment: This may help: http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/hyphens_in_compound_adjectives.htm

Comment: @TheBeeferFan Please read [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/2753/16040) to know how to use Mrs., Miss, and Ms. and also avoid thanking for every edit, and adding a title like "Mr."/"Mrs." to everyone's username online. Try to be gender-neutral.
Also avoid calling everyone "my friend".

Comment: @Neeku Sorry. I try harder to make it good but it very difficult. I try be polite and get wrong.

Comment: Just in case others are misled: this is a joke/troll account that asks silly and deliberately disingenuous questions that nonetheless require a bit of lateral thinking to locate the actual jokes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a hyphen whenever you're using a compound adjective for a noun that is being used as a single descriptor for the noun.

For example in the phrase you provided, **graded-reading** is a single descriptor all together for the noun **books**, and saying **graded books**, or **reading books** separately, won't make sense to imply what you mean. So, yes, you must use a hyphen there.

Read this article [here](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/040201hyphadj.htm).

Answer (score 3):

If the books are about reading that is graded then yes, you can use a hyphen (probably what you need).

If the books are about reading and the books themselves are graded don't use a hyphen.

Also, check out [ell](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you my frend. But what is a difference between dash and hyphen?

Comment: That's not a minus sign; it's a hyphen. Compare. This is a hyphen: -. This is a minus sign: −. It looks a lot like an en dash: –. The minus sign and hyphen were combined on the typewriter and ASCII and early computer systems, but they've always been different in typesetting and are different in Unicode (which is what should count today).

Comment: rephrasing my previous comment: A hyphen is shorter. Unless you are publishing something it doesn't really matter. You are probably using the hyphen anyway and that should be fine. hyphen/minus sign/en dash/em dash: - − – —